# JavaScript: Using document.write();

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to create a new HTML doc using `document.write` INSIDE another `document.write` in JavaScript.

I know this is a painful way to do it (and feel free to rewrite the code with the desired output), but here it is:

```js
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                newDoc.write("<html><head><title>Failure!</title></head><body><h5>js::error 5015 &&syn.0</h5><p>In Quantum Mechanisms exists a quantum state known as quantum superposition - the state of being two things at once given a random subatomic event that may or may not occur.</p><p>A famous experiment by Erwin Schrödinger, a cat was placed in a box along with a poison flask that would kill the cat, only activating if a subatomic change was detected (which is completely random). The thought experiment brought forth the idea of the cat being <em>dead</em> and <em>alive</em> at the same exact time, but you aren't able to know which it is. So in theory, by opening the box and finding that the cat is dead, you have essentially killed the cat yourself.</p><p>Quantum Mechanics have been applied to the button you just clicked. The choice was yours on whether or not to click it, and you did not know where you would end up. You can say that it would have unlocked a new upgrade, or break the game, but since you clicked the button, you therefore must have broken the game yourself. Just like that, curiosity killed the cat. Sorry, quantum superposition is pretty terrible. Fortunately, you can click this button below to continue on your journey.</p><button onclick=\"var newDoc = document.open(\"text/html\", \"replace\"); newDoc.write(\"<html><head><title>Double Fail</title></head><body><p>No seriously, quantum mechanics are pretty bad. :)</p></body></html>\"); newDoc.close();\">Continue</button></body></html>");
                newDoc.close();
```

As you can see, the button is not outputting the information clearly. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: document.write is depreciated and no longer used by modern developers. Use DOM manipulation to add and remove elements.

Comment: What does clearly mean ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you'd want to use `document.write` even once, let alone twice?

Comment: @Hanoncs Can you be a little more specific as to where I can find the information to do this type of task? By clearly, if you look at the output of the code snippet, the button text is all messed up.

Comment: @Hanoncs _for no reason_?! You copied and pasted an entire W3 article into an answer.

Comment: @Hanoncs: People want to downvote with good reason, which I started typing but you got insulted too fast. The reason is, copy-pasting an entire article from W3C on DOM manipulation would be a bad form even if the question was on DOM manipulation. It is not - it is on `document.write`. We already said in comments that `document.write` is a bad idea in comments; if OP wants to know more about DOM manipulation, he should make another question about it (or ideally, research more on his own before making another question). The only reason I did not flag you with Not An Answer is I had no time to.

Comment: @Amadan I didn't get offended, just wanted a reason. I agree. It is not related to the original question. I removed it.

Comment: @LegendaryB3ast Here is a good starting point http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: @Hanoncs: Very well then, I apologise for jumping to conclusions. But if you truly want to know why someone downvoted you, you should give it a bit more time than 20 seconds - I for one, and many in the community, will almost always explain the downvote. And sometimes someone will, indeed, downvote and not state a reason; and if there was no reason, and your answer is good enough, someone else will probably upvote it, which is worth like 5 downvotes in reputation. But none of this voting or explaining can happen if you disappear your answer at the first hint of downvotage.

Comment: Sounds good sir. I just didn't want a bunch of down votes right away, so I removed it. Thank you for being polite and not flaming me. I'm still learning stack. Enjoy the rest of your day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of escaping needs to happen:

```js
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
                newDoc.write('<html><head><title>Failure!</title></head><body><h5>js::error 5015 &&syn.0</h5><p>In Quantum Mechanisms exists a quantum state known as quantum superposition - the state of being two things at once given a random subatomic event that may or may not occur.</p><p>A famous experiment by Erwin Schrödinger, a cat was placed in a box along with a poison flask that would kill the cat, only activating if a subatomic change was detected (which is completely random). The thought experiment brought forth the idea of the cat being <em>dead</em> and <em>alive</em> at the same exact time, but you aren\'t able to know which it is. So in theory, by opening the box and finding that the cat is dead, you have essentially killed the cat yourself.</p><p>Quantum Mechanics have been applied to the button you just clicked. The choice was yours on whether or not to click it, and you did not know where you would end up. You can say that it would have unlocked a new upgrade, or break the game, but since you clicked the button, you therefore must have broken the game yourself. Just like that, curiosity killed the cat. Sorry, quantum superposition is pretty terrible. Fortunately, you can click this button below to continue on your journey.</p><button onclick="var newDoc = document.open(\'text/html\', \'replace\'); newDoc.write(\'<html><head><title>Double Fail</title></head><body><p>No seriously, quantum mechanics are pretty bad. :)</p></body></html>\'); newDoc.close();">Continue</button></body></html>');
                newDoc.close();
```

Here's where the problem starts:

```
</p><button onclick=\"var newDoc = document.open(\"text/html\"
                     ^^ starting onclick         ^^ ending it
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
newDoc.write("<html><head><title>Failure!</title></head><body>Button:<button onclick=\"var newDoc = document.open(&quot;text/html&quot;, &quot;replace&quot;); newDoc.write(&quot;<html><head><title>Double Fail</title></head><body><p>Button clicked.</p></body></html>&quot;); newDoc.close();\">Continue</button></body></html>");
newDoc.close();
```

Your quoting is bad. The generated HTML will break on `"`, you need to employ HTML escaping (`&quot;`) inside your `onclick` attribute, not JavaScript escaping (`\"`) at that point.